# After updating targetSDK to 28 ,Snackbar is giving error?

Tags: android, sdk, android-snackbar

After updating my `targetSDK` version to 28, I am not able to use the SnackBar

> Must be one of BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE,
>   BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_SHORT,
>   BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG or value must be ≥ 1 (was -2)
>   less... Inspection info: Ensures that when parameter in a method only
>   allows a specific set of constants, calls obey those rules.

[image: My Sample Code]

Here is what I have done -

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(Objects.requireNonNull(parentLayout), "Kindly allow all the permissions for  App  for a better  experience...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
 snackbar.setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
 snackbar.show();
```

Comment: I can not understand you are already giving duration value to the snackbar in make method as the third parameter than why you give it again to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [**setDuration**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BaseTransientBottomBar.html#setDuration(int))

> snackbar.setDuration(int duration);

Set how long to show the view for. You should try with

```
snackbar.setDuration(10000);
```

Comment: It is working but what happened to Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE before the set duration is accepted this.

Comment: @creativecoder `LENGTH_INDEFINITE` will show the Snackbar for and indefinite period of time. It will be better if you use `LENGTH_LONG`.

Comment: @creativecoder oh, for that case use hard coded int value.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Material from `'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` to version `'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'` fixed this for me.